# I want ORDER BY some field with DESC

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data (it's id) :

```
SB-1
SB-10
SB-9
```

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM sb ORDER BY id DESC
```

The result is :

```
SB-9
SB-10
SB-1
```

I want my result is :

```
SB-10
SB-9
SB-1
```

How is the query for that?

Comment: If, as is implied, id is a PRIMARY KEY, then you may want to reconsider its design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM sb
ORDER BY LENGTH(id) DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: By using a function in the ORDER BY clause, the database engine won't be able to use any indexes which can lead to poor query performance. Properly designing the model would help (separate the alphabetic and numeric parts of the key). Having a value something like SB-02 will break this query.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine.

Answer (score 0):

use  `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and pick the int value then do order by

```
select * , cast( SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name,'-',-1)  as unsigned ) as v
from table_name order by v desc
```

and need explicit conversion

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a25a886d319453edccf525d370edf9c0)

Comment: @GentaHaetamiPutra you can accept only one answer, not all probably you marked all sequentially :)

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
select * , cast( replace(id,'SB-','')  as int ) as newid
from tablename order by newid desc
```